# Function won't reverse strings properly

Tags: visual-c++, c-strings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;




void reverseString(char s[])
{
    int length = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[length - i - 1];
        s[length - i - 1] = temp;

        cout << s[i];   //this ends up printing "eooe" instead of reversing the whole string
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    char a[] = "Shoe"; 
    reverseString(a);

    return 1;
}
```

I'm wondering where the algorithm messes up and what I can do to fix it, maybe I overlooked something because when I try to solve it on a piece of paper it appears to work correctly.

Comment: The reverse algorithm is fine - try putting `cout << s;` after the for loop exits.

Comment: @jjim won't that just print out the argument passed through the function, without it being reversed?

Comment: Nope, you're modifying the string in place.

Answer (score 2):

Your algo is right but need a little modification, you have to run algorithm for `length/2` times. It prevents your string to again swap the contents i.e At `i = 2` your `s = eohs` but it again swaps `h` with `o`. Try to insert the break point to understand it further. I modify your function little bit.

```
char* reverseString(char s[])
{
    int length = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i<length/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[length - i - 1];
        s[length - i - 1] = temp;
        //cout << s[i];   //this ends up printing "eooe" instead of reversing the whole string
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "Shoe";
    cout<<reverseString(a);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strrev(char *p)
{
  char *q = p;
  while(q && *q) ++q;
  for(--q; p < q; ++p, --q)
    *p = *p ^ *q,
    *q = *p ^ *q,
    *p = *p ^ *q;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  do {
    printf("%s ",  argv[argc-1]);
    strrev(argv[argc-1]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[argc-1]);
  } while(--argc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: we have a main `char *p` and we copy `p`  address into the `q` pointer. after that, we move `q` address from first string, to end of string with `while` loop. then we replace the first value with end value with `for` loop and XOR operator (with bit operation). if you want to know, please trace that with an example.